# payable function not working

Tags: payable

```
function() payable external {
    eth_balance[msg.sender] += msg.value;  
}
```

This is not working. The execution is reverted and uses about 21,000 gas. No matter if I set the gas crazy high like 800,000 it still fails. This is on rinkeby network. Any ideas? I'm using Remix IDE.

Comment: What `msg.value` are you using and what is the balance of `msg.sender`?

Comment: Or in other words, a wild guess: `msg.sender.balance < msg.value`.

Comment: is eth_balance a mapping between address -> uint256 ?

Comment: Yes, yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the contract is fine. The gas during certain times, no matter how high it's set will not allow the transaction to go through. I believe a lot of it has ethereum congestion. If you run into similar situations I would set the contract gas to something like 800,000 gas on the test network and try a different time of day.